# Cannot set property 'running' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt.js and I have this problem, with reading the *running* property of my *client* object.

HTML:

```
<b-button
  v-show="!(projectSelecter(project.ID)).isStarted"  //this work just fine
  variant="success"
  class="control_buttons"
  @click="start(project.ID)"
>Start</b-button>
```

JS:

```
start: function(id) {
  const client=this.projectSelecter(id);
  console.log("ID: ", id);
  console.log("Client: ", client);
  console.log("Client running property: ", client.running);
  //if (client.running) return;

  if (client.timeBegan === null) {
    this.reset();
    client.timeBegan = new Date();
  }

  if (client.timeStopped !== null) {
    client.stoppedDuration += new Date() - client.timeStopped;
  }

  client.isStarted=!client.isStarted;
  client.started = setInterval(this.clockRunning, 10);
  client.running = true;
},
```

This is the reset function, which is called in the start function above.

```
reset: function(id) {
  var client=this.projectSelecter(id);
  client.running = false;
  clearInterval(client.started);
  client.stoppedDuration = 0;
  client.timeBegan = null;
  client.timeStopped = null;
  client.time = "00:00";
  client.isStarted=false;
}
```

Console logs:

[image]

Error message:

[image]

Full:

[image]

Comment: what is the output of `console.log("ID: ", id);
  console.log("Client: ", client);`

Comment: Hello. I have pictures of them. See in the Console logs section

Comment: test it with `console.log(client.running);`

Comment: since running is `false`, it won't go inside your if loop. What is the code below the 'if' loop

Comment: I will show you just a moment

Comment: I can get the property just cannot set it

Comment: What does your this.reset() method do? It might be the culprit.

Comment: I just added the reset function

Comment: Well, clearly `client === undefined` in your `reset` method, so `this.projectSelecter(id)` must be returning `undefined`. But you haven't show us that method, so we can't tell what might be going wrong there. Please take a look at our help page on creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and try to follow it.

Comment: ...oh, never mind, it's obvious: your `reset` method wants an `id` as a parameter, but you don't give it one. So obviously *something* is going to go wrong.

Comment: Yes, I just saw that, thank you for your help. I think I need to rest

Comment: That's always a good idea. Also consider practicing [how to use a debugger](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript) better; this *should've* been an easy bug to diagnose if you'd just set a breakpoint somewhere in your `start` method and stepped through the code to see what it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `reset` method,
You need to pass `id` as parameter in the start method.
So your start method should look like

```
start: function(id) {
  const client=this.projectSelecter(id);
  console.log("ID: ", id);
  console.log("Client: ", client);
  console.log("Client running property: ", client.running);
  //if (client.running) return;

  if (client.timeBegan === null) {
    this.reset(id); //passing `id` to reset method
    client.timeBegan = new Date();
  }

  if (client.timeStopped !== null) {
    client.stoppedDuration += new Date() - client.timeStopped;
  }

  client.isStarted=!client.isStarted;
  client.started = setInterval(this.clockRunning, 10);
  client.running = true;
},
```